# Saving an entity to the DB in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I've looked at so many posts about this, but still haven't found the solution:

I'm using a winforms app that uses EntityFramework (6?).  When I load the form I can read from the DB using the context (Entities).  However, when I savechanges after adding a new entity, it doesn't persist to the db.

```
var c = new Card { Name = tbName.Text, Quantity = int.Parse(tbQuantity.Text) };
dbContext.Cards.Add(c);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The dbContext is setup in the form constructor and is an instance of "LiquorTrackEntities".

```
LiquorTrackEntities dbContext;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dbContext = new LiquorTrackEntities()
```

Reading from the db works:

```
var cards = dbContext.Cards.ToList();
```

I do this stuff all the time in asp.net MVC, but it isn't working in WinForms.. is there something special I have to do in winforms?  I also know about the normal "using (var db = new LiquorEntitiesEntities())" convention, but I just want to get this functioning before I worry about convention.

Any ideas?

Just tried this to no avail:

```
var c = new Card { Name = tbName.Text, Quantity = int.Parse(tbQuantity.Text) };
dbContext.Cards.Attach(c);
dbContext.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Added;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Just tried creating a new EDMX using EF5 instead.. same problem.

UPDATE: 
SaveChanges does return a 1 when after adding a card.  It stays in the context (if I reload my cards from the context, the new one is there..) but never makes it to the database.

Comment: I've also tried making a new version of the context, it doesn't matter how I format this, it doesn't write to the db.

Comment: Also tried "attaching" the new entity to the context.  Also doesn't work.\

Comment: Define doesn't work. Do you receive an error of any kind?

Comment: No errors, just nothing shows up in the table.

Comment: By calling `new LiquorTrackEntities()` you don't pass any connection-string parameter. are you sure it doesn't use some sort of LocalDB \ SQLExpress by default?

Comment: It might!  But it does read from the correct db.  I have some sample data in there, that is loaded properly.

Comment: Whats the alternative to calling new LiquorTrackEntities()?  I don't see an overload..

Comment: You're looking at two different databases. Check to which database the application connects.